# Are Hindus descendants of Surya and Chandra Vamshis?

Tags: history, india, gotra

Are all Hindus, or at least all Indian Hindus descendants of Suryavamshis and Chandravamshis?

Kindly through some light.

Comment: Some Hindu Kshatriyas are suryavashi and chandravanshi. The original name of the religion is indeed vedic religion (vaidika dharma or sanatana dharma). If you are referring to Jaggi Vasudev, I say discount almost everything he says. He is not very literate in religion or scripture or even common history and geography.

Comment: this [q/a](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-hinduism-did-not-get-propagated-to-entire-world/18014#18014) might answer some of ur questions. also, i think we're mostly chandravamsh now (after Krishna's period), while during Rama's period, it was suryavamsh.

Comment: @ram There are  suryavanshis in kali yuga....only kshatriya kulas are surya or chandra vamshis.

Comment: see similar [question/answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-hinduism-did-not-get-propagated-to-entire-world/18014)

Comment: Rajputs are descended. They are Agni Vanshi as well.

Comment: @Aghori All rajputs are kshatriyas how do you think they were so courageous and powerful if they weren't kshatriyas.

Comment: @Yogi can't get you.

Comment: @Aghori Rajputs were so powerful because they were Kshatriya descendents as you said Agni Vanshi.